# Lookup contacts instead of accounts on emails in MS Dynamics CRM 2013

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2013

I planning change default view for `to` attribute on `email` entity, so instead of `account` entity it will suggest user to choose recipients among `contacts`.

However this functionality in MS Dynamics CRM seems to be broken. Or I missing something?

Here is the code:

```
(function () {
    var ctrl = Xrm.Page.getControl("to");

    if (ctrl) {
        ctrl.setDefaultView('{13C1A58B-9AEF-4164-80E5-1D946D5BC8B3}');
        console.log("Default view is set!");
    }
}())
```

Guid points to valid view on `contact` entity. The code is executed, console has debug message <kbd>Default view is set!</kbd>, and on using `to` lookup system still uses `account` by default.

Did somebody found workaround for this issue? In supported way, of course.

Comment: I think it has to do with the fact that the field is an activityparty, if I rembember correctly setDefaultView is supported only on standard lookups

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was lucky to find supported, but still a bit tricky way how to achieve needed result without hacking CRM core.

The basic idea is to add **any custom view** to selected control, and than `setDefaultView` to **any needed view** that valid for the entity.

So code in the question could be rewritten as:

```
(function () {
    var ctrl = Xrm.Page.getControl("to");

    if (ctrl) {
        // Add custom view based 
        ctrl.addCustomView('{71C254C1-1F55-43B7-94DE-C461DB617A77}', 'contact', 'View Name', '<xml> valid FetchXML statement </xml>', '<xml> valid LayoutXML statement </xml>', true);
        ctrl.setDefaultView('{13C1A58B-9AEF-4164-80E5-1D946D5BC8B3}');
        console.log("Default view is set!");
    }
}())
```

Actually after new custom view is set, any valid view could be set as default. This could be either custom or system view.

Comment: Confirmed that the same code works for the Customer type fields as well.
Thanks.