# How to set the default type for an Activity Entity in Microsoft Dynamics?

Tags: javascript, typescript, dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics

I am refactoring some script code that is attached to the Fax Activity Entity in Microsoft Dynamics.  In the script code I see:

```
document.getElementById("regardingobjectid").setAttribute("defaulttype", "2");
```

From what I understand, accessing the DOM from a Web Resource is unsupported in Dynamics.  I would like to change this code to be something like the following:

```
Xrm.Page.getAttribute("regardingobjectid").setValue({defaulttype: 2})
```

Unfortunately, I can't find any documentation regarding setting the `defaulttype` property for the `regardingobjectid` field.  I see some things about setting other properties, but none specifically for `regardingobjectid`.  How can I set the `defaulttype` in a supported way?

Comment: I have not tried this undocumented (unsupported) setLookupTypes, but will give a try. https://dreamingincrm.com/2016/06/02/restricting-the-customer-lookup/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct that code is unsupported and should be avoided.

The regarding (`regardingobjectid`) field is a lookup field which allows many different entity types; contact, account, etc.

When a user opens the Look Up Record popup via 'Look Up More Records' link, it will display the default entity (account) first. The user can manually select a different entity type, but that requires more clicks.

In this case I believe the previous coder is trying to change the default entity type to contact. Google `.setAttribute("defaulttype", "2")` and there are plenty of hits describing the process.

I'm not 100% sure if there is a supported way to achieve this. Googling suggests there are a number of people trying to achieve this behaviour and struggling. There is a [feature request open](https://ideas.dynamics.com/ideas/dynamics-crm/727766) for this type of behaviour.

That said I believe using `setDefaultView` should work ([MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg334266.aspx#BKMK_setDefaultView)).

`Xrm.Page.getControl("regardingobjectid").setDefaultView("{00000000-0000-0000-00AA-000010001003}");`

Where the Guid is the id of a contact view.

Related; [Lookup contacts instead of accounts on emails in MS Dynamics CRM 2013](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29256667/lookup-contacts-instead-of-accounts-on-emails-in-ms-dynamics-crm-2013)